# Enable syntax highlighting on RPG.SE

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting, code-formatting

### Request

Please enable syntax highlighting on [rpg.stackexchange.com](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/).

### Justification

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314554/419891), users can present feature requests to add syntax highlighting to StackExchange properties. [rpg.stackexchange.com](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/) is one such property that currently does not support syntax highlighting. Anecdotally, code snippets appear in a minority of questions and responses, but when they do, they can be quite valuable (e.g., for simulations or in support of various theory). Syntax highlighting can make such snippets more accessible, even to those not intimately familiar with the languages.

*UPDATE: Below is a sample from posts* **excluding [`anydice` questions and answers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anydice)** *where syntax highlighting would be helpful, but this is far from exhaustive. Note that in almost every answer (and many questions) in [`anydice`](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anydice) would also benefit from almost any curly brace language syntax highlighter (e.g., c).*

- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/28608/71245
- [Untyped strength bonus in Herolab](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/30003/71245)
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/46296/71245
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/46314/71245
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/65440/71245
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/63160/71245
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/96355/71245
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/63412/71245
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/78712/71245
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/80288/71245
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/90820/71245
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/100426/71245
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/181910/71245
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/124993/71245
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/125650/71245
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/138507/71245
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/166663/71245
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/183625/71245
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/179895/71245
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/179045/71245
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/179047/71245
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/198632/71245
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/200357/71245
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/201379/71245
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/202075/71245
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/202128/71245
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/204052/71245
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/204069/71245
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/205011/71245
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/205026/71245
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/205009/71245
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/205080/71245
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/205102/71245
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/205988/71245
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/207193/71245
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/207979/71245

Comment: How can I find out? My sense is that it comes up frequently with statistics and anydice tags (among others).

Comment: [Hascode](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=Hascode%3Ayes) is a start.

Comment: @Laurel The majority of those posts are misused code formatting.

Comment: The how to request syntax highlighting section states: "In this case, link to some (10 or so) posts where highlighting would be helpful in your request".

Comment: Updated with list as recommended.

Comment: Syntax highlighting ***doesn't*** slow down page load. To the extent it might involve a script needing to be loaded, the script loading is deferred — it happens later, after the page has already loaded, and you load it _just once_ and then it's cached. To the extent it affects a page, an answer with code with syntax highlighting will have more elements — but if we're concerned about that we should be worried about the page load requirements of bold, italic, and text formatting. It's _not_ stuff to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

#### The juice isn’t worth the squeeze *if* this causes disruption for anyone.

Posts containing code supported by SE’s syntax highlighting make up a very small fraction of our posts and page views. This shouldn’t be surprising: coding isn’t what this site is about. Now, your contributions here are valuable - you have consistently provided innovative solutions to probability questions on this site with the suite of tools you have developed. But the questions you answer with python solutions are a very tiny fraction of this site’s scope. Because of this, if there is any chance at all that turning this on for our site causes disruption for anyone, we shouldn’t do it. The small net positive in readability to a niche corner of our site isn’t worth disrupting everything else for even a single reader.

Comment: I think this is unhelpfully hyperbolic: a net positive in readability in some parts of the site is definitely worth disrupting, like, one guy. That's the _classic_ [you broke my workflow](https://xkcd.com/1172/) scenario. We can assess whether there's meaningful gain and any meaningful loss and we don't need hyperbolic extremes like “you can't disrupt anything _at all_ for _anybody_” in that assessment, nor do I think an ideology like that is healthy for us to sign up to.

Comment: @doppelgreener My personal opinion of what we gain is that it really isn’t worth disrupting one guy. That’s my opinion of the gain here, so I’ve shared it since no one else responded after several days. I’m not sure hyperbolic is the right word though. I really just don’t think the value is there. But you’re of course welcome to disagree. I’ve shared so the community could vote on it.

Comment: @KRyan Whether or not you agree with my take, do you think the new header is more appropriate?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Yes, I think that works much better, thanks. I’ll un-downvote, for now; I don’t know if I buy “for even one person” as a criterion, but at least this is clear that it’s suggesting a criterion, not claiming that this criterion has been met.